# PCI-X compatible with PCI Express

Tags: pci-express

I have a dell disk array that is a few years old as well as a pci-x scsi card. I would like to put pci-x scsi card in my dell r805. The dell r805 only has 4 pci express slots and no pci-x slots. I have searched all over google and have not found out the answer. Will the pci-x card work in the pci express slot in my r805?

Comment: You must have skipped the first page of google results. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X

Comment: Dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/104747/pci-x-compatible-with-pci-express

Comment: I don't know where you got that link from Dan but right now it's giving a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't work, they're physically and electrically incompatible. Let us know what model of disk array you have and we'll try to find you something that will work.

Comment: It is a dell powervault 220s.

Comment: I bought an LSI pci express card. It works wonderfully. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

No it will not, PCI-X and PCI-E are very different hardware devices. Definitely not compatible.